# iOS reload MKMapView every time view the app its load

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, mkmapview

I'm implementing MKMapView app but I'm trying to reload the data and the zoom animation when the app comes back from background. I implement this on AppDelegate:

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
        [self.viewController.mapView setRegion:self.viewController.mapView.region animated:YES];
}
```

I don't want t use

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{
}
```

because it maybe the same location still wants to reload the map in the view.

Any of you knows how can I reload the map and all the data in the map?

I'll really appreciate your help

Comment: What do you mean by reload the map? Are you expecting the roads to have moved and to get new data from Apple? Do you just mean refresh your own data that you are drawing on the map?

Comment: And does the code on applicationWillEnterForeground work? It should if you only have one view controller on your app